# How can I save a transform movement state to json?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It's a bit long but these scripts are connected. The whole saving system has some more scripts but these 3 scripts the most important for this case.

For now, I can save the state of a transform position rotation scaling.
but the saving is static, I mean I can save the current transform position rotation scaling but I want to save the state of it in run-time dynamic save.

For example, if I have a transform that moves to some position or between some positions so I want to save the transform current position but also to save the transform moving direction and when loading back the saved game state the transform should keep moving to the next position with the same speed and direction.

Same logic if a transform is scaling up/down for example from 5 to 1 and from 1 to 5 so to save the current scaling but also when loading to continue the scaling.

Same for rotation.

This is the transform saver class :

using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

```
[Serializable]
public class TransformSaver
{
    public Vector3 position;
    public Vector3 scaling;
    public Quaternion rotation;
}
```

Then the save load script :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SaveLoad : MonoBehaviour
{
    public FadeInOutSaveGameText fadeInOutSaveGame;
    public float timeToStartSaving;
    public float savingFadeInOutTime;

    private string saveString;

    private void Awake()
    {
        SaveSystem.Init();
    }

    public void Save(string Folder, string FileName)
    {
        var objectsToSave = UpdateObjectsToSave();

        SaveGame saveGame = new SaveGame();
        saveGame.saveObjects = new List<SaveObject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToSave.Count; i++)
        {
            SaveObject saveObject = new SaveObject();
            saveObject.transformSaver = new TransformSaver();
            
            Debug.Log($"{i}");
            Debug.Log($"{objectsToSave[i].name}");
            saveObject.gameObjectUniqueID = objectsToSave[i].GetComponent<GenerateGuid>().uniqueGuidID;
            var x = objectsToSave[i].GetComponents<Component>();
            var stateQueryComponent = x.Where(component => component is IStateQuery).ToList();
            List<KeyToValue> componentsState = new List<KeyToValue>();
            foreach (var z in stateQueryComponent)
            {
                var w = z as IStateQuery;
                componentsState.Add(new KeyToValue(w.UniqueId.ToString(), w.GetState()));
            }

            saveObject.transformSaver.position = objectsToSave[i].transform.position;
            saveObject.transformSaver.rotation = objectsToSave[i].transform.rotation;
            saveObject.transformSaver.scaling = objectsToSave[i].transform.localScale;

            saveObject.componentsState = componentsState;
            saveGame.saveObjects.Add(saveObject);
        }

        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(saveGame);

        if (Folder == null && FileName == null)
        {
            SaveSystem.Save(json);
        }
        else
        {
            SaveSystem.Save(Folder, FileName, json);
        }
    }

    public void Load(string Folder, string FileName)
    {
       var objectsToLoad =  UpdateObjectsToSave();

        Dictionary<string, GameObject> uniqueIdToObject = objectsToLoad
            .ToDictionary(o => o.GetComponent<GenerateGuid>().uniqueGuidID, o => o);

        saveString = SaveSystem.Load(Folder, FileName);

        if (saveString != null)
        {
            SaveGame saveGame = JsonUtility.FromJson<SaveGame>(saveString);
            foreach (var saveObject in saveGame.saveObjects)
            {
                List<KeyToValue> loadedComponents = saveObject.componentsState;

                if (uniqueIdToObject.ContainsKey(saveObject.gameObjectUniqueID))
                {
                    var objectToSetState = uniqueIdToObject[saveObject.gameObjectUniqueID];

                    objectToSetState.transform.position = saveObject.transformSaver.position;
                    objectToSetState.transform.rotation = saveObject.transformSaver.rotation;
                    objectToSetState.transform.localScale = saveObject.transformSaver.scaling;

                    var y = objectToSetState.GetComponents<Component>();
                    var z = y.Where(component => component is IStateQuery).ToList();
                    Dictionary<string, IStateQuery> zz = z.ToDictionary(sq => (sq as IStateQuery).UniqueId.ToString(), sq => sq as IStateQuery);

                    foreach (KeyToValue keyvalue in loadedComponents)
                    {
                        zz[keyvalue.Key].SetState(keyvalue.Value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private List<GameObject> UpdateObjectsToSave()
    {
        var objectsWithGenerateGuid = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<GenerateGuid>().ToList();
        var objectsToSave = new List<GameObject>();

        if (objectsWithGenerateGuid.Count > 0 && objectsToSave.Count == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < objectsWithGenerateGuid.Count; i++)
            {
                objectsToSave.Add(objectsWithGenerateGuid[i].gameObject);
            }
        }

        return objectsToSave;
    }

    public IEnumerator AuatomaticSaveWithTime()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeToStartSaving);

        Save(null, null);

        StartCoroutine(fadeInOutSaveGame.OverAllTime(savingFadeInOutTime));
    }

    public IEnumerator SaveWithTime(string Folder, string FileName)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeToStartSaving);

        Save(Folder, FileName);

        StartCoroutine(fadeInOutSaveGame.OverAllTime(savingFadeInOutTime));
    }
}
```

In the Save method at lines 46-48 I'm getting the transform information of the positon , rotation , scaling and then save them to a son file.

but now I want to check if the transform is in a moving and then to save the current moving state like speed and direction.

In the Lod method lines 86-88 I'm getting the transform information and et it back.

This is a simple example of state script to save a state in this case a flag state :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class StateTest : MonoBehaviour, IStateQuery
{
    private bool hasOpened;

    private State m_state = new State();

    public Guid UniqueId => Guid.Parse("88EE7288-1B1C-47D2-9981-29D1804B71A7");


    private class State
    {
        public bool open;
        // bool the kid holding the navi is true
    }

    public string GetState()
    {
        return JsonUtility.ToJson(m_state);
    }

    public void SetState(string jsonString)
    {
        m_state = JsonUtility.FromJson<State>(jsonString);

        if(m_state.open)
        {
            hasOpened = true;

            Debug.Log("Open !");
        }
        else
        {
            hasOpened = false;

            Debug.Log("Close !");
        }
    }



    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.O))
        {
            hasOpened = true;

            Debug.Log("Open !");
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
        {
            hasOpened = false;

            Debug.Log("Close !");
        }

        m_state.open = hasOpened;
    }
}
```

I just created a local open/close flag state but what if I want to save the transform the script state is attached to movement ? so when loading it will position the transform in the saved position but also will keep moving the transform.

Comment: `JsonUtility.ToJson(m_state)` will indeed only save the boolean value of the `m_state` variable to json. If you want to add additional data such as the position of the transform you should create a class structured to store all this and use json to serialize and deserialize an instance of said class.

Comment: You could delay the saving by one frame and use the two frames in order to calculate the delta and thereby velocity between the two frames

Answer (score 1):

> I have a transform that moves to some position or between some positions

Do you have an event called when your transform starts moving? If so you could save :

- the initial position the transform was when it started moving,
- the Time value of when it started moving,
- the actual position of the transform (what you are actually doing),
- and the Time value of when you saved the position.

With those informations you could position the transform at the loading, then calculate the direction it was going in with the initial position of the transform.
And then calculate the speed with the time spent between the beginning of the movement and the moment you saved the position and the distance travelled ([formula to calculate the speed](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/math/speed-distance-time-calculator.php#:%7E:text=To%20solve%20for%20speed%20or,equals%20distance%20divided%20by%20time.&text=To%20solve%20for%20time%20use,equals%20distance%20divided%20by%20speed.))